# Numpy.dtype has wrong size PyOpenGL

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pyopengl

This seems to be an internal problem with my installation of `PyOpenGL`. I recently installed `PyOpenGL 3.1.0` and `numpy 1.8.1` on my system (I am currently using Ubuntu 16.10) for Python 2.7, but my testing immediately because for the program I want to write, the specific import I need is `OpenGL_accelerate.numpy_formathandler`, however, when I import this package, I get the error: `ValueError: numpy.dtype has wrong size, try recompiling`. I took this to mean either my `numpy` version was wrong, or I just needed to re-install one or both of the packages. I tried upgrading `numpy` to it's most recent release, to no avail. Then I tried uninstalling and re-installing both packages, `PyOpenGL` at version 3.1.0 each time, and `numpy` both at versions 1.8.1 and the most recent version. I am at a complete loss at what to do here. If anyone has had this issue or a very similar one, please help! I have already looked around at other questions for an answer and none of them have seemed to help so far.